Position of Muhammad (PBUH) under Khadija
We know that apart from becoming husband of Khadija, Muhammad (PBUH) did job under her.
What was the name of the position of that job? (I understand there was no recruitment advertisement or job description like today, but still there must be a name even if that is simply 'assistant'.)
Reference required.

The Prophet ﷺ participated in a Mudarabah with her. This is a business partnership where one party contributes all the capital and the other party does all the work, and the profit is shared between the partners in some ratio. The one who does the work is typically called Mudarib. The Prophet ﷺ traveled to Syria for trade on her behalf. See Al-Bidaya wa'l-Nihaya.

That's not a job, that's business. I learnt that he did job under her first few years of their meeting.

@Kawrno That's simply not correct, unless you can bring references.
